# FluentPDO é seguro?

Tags: php, pdo

Alguém que já chegou a usar o [FluentPDO](http://fluentpdo.com/documentation.html#features), sabe me informar se ele é seguro em relação a SQL Injects? Tudo bem que ele usa PDO, mas de repente ele não trata os dados antes de ser enviado para a base de dados.

E caso ela for segura, pretendo estudá-la para desenvolver minha própria `model` utilizando PDO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende da forma como ele é usado. Observando os exemplos na página linkada, temos:

```
syntax                           description
$table->where("field", "x")      Translated to field = 'x'
$table->where("field > ?", "x")  bound by PDO
```

Como você pode ver, o primeiro caso simplesmente coloca o valor utilizado na query, sem nenhum tratamento adicional. Se você usar um valor tipo:

```
$table->where("field", "Robert'); DROP TABLE Students;--")
```

Então ele será colocado na query, e você sofrerá uma Injeção de SQL. Entretanto, se você usar a segunda forma:

```
$table->where("field = ?", "Robert'); DROP TABLE Students;--")
```

Então a `'` no valor será "escapada", e seu sistema estará seguro.

Em resumo, usar FluentPDO não vai automaticamente tornar seu sistema seguro ou inseguro, é necessário levar cada chamada da API em consideração, caso a caso, ao determinar a segurança da aplicação.

Comment: Grato pela resposta! :)